# Debug Spring Boot application in VSC

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have one simple Spring boot app that runs normally in console. 
But I can't debug it in VSC.

The code is:

```
package com.sample.service.sample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

/**
 * sample service
 *
 */
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.sample.service.sample.repositories")
public class ServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The exception is:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objenesis/strategy/InstantiatorStrategy
```

What did I miss in VSC setting for Spring Boot?

Comment: I think you may have conflicting versions of `objenesis` dependency or missing dependency in your class path. Please add the appropriate version of the dependency in you build path.

Comment: Please, publish also your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`.